# Clarification on Theorem 4.1 Milnor's lecture on h-cobordism theorem. Why The set $K_p$ is compact?

Tags: differential-topology, gradient-flows

I need a clarification about a passage in the statement of [Theorem $4.1$ of Milnor's Lectures on the H-cobordism theorem](https://books.google.com/books?id=_znWCgAAQBAJ&q=4.1#v=snippet&q=preliminary%20rearrangement&f=false)

> Suppose that for some choice of gradient-like vector field $\xi$, the **compact** set $K_p$ of points on trajectories going to or from $p$ is disjoint from  the **compact** set $K_{p'}$ of points on trajectories going to or from $p'$.

I don't understand why the set $K_p$ or $K_{p'}$ should be **closed** (hence compact since we are working in a compact manifold).

This **must** use the fact that we have only $2$ critical point in our manifold with boundary, $p_1,p_2$, otherwise the statement is not true (a flow line might converge to a broken flow-line).

Here is my attempt. Let $\gamma \colon \Bbb R \times W \to W$ be the flow of $\xi$. Let $\{x_n\}_n \subset K_p$ and assume that $\gamma_t(x_n)\to p$ for $t\to \infty$. Let $x_n \to x$ for $n\to \infty$. We want to prove that $\gamma_t(x)\to p$ for $t\to \infty$. We have the following estimate:

\begin{align}
 \mid \gamma_t(x)-p\mid &\leq \mid \gamma_t(x)-\gamma_t(x_n)\mid +\mid \gamma_t(x_n)-p\mid\\
&\leq \mid \gamma_t(x)-\gamma_t(x_n)\mid +\epsilon
\end{align}

for $t>>M$.

I don't see how to use the critical assumption that we have only two critical points because I'd be tempted to use continuity of $\gamma_t$ to claim that I can bound $\mid \gamma_t(x)-\gamma_t(x_n)\mid$ by taking $x_n$ sufficiently closed to $x$.

Can someone clarify what's wrong with my reasoning?